# Exception handling with multiple objects

Tags: c++, exception

The code does not go to the second line in `try` statement. Please help me find the error.

It should also check for the second object.

According to the question, this program shall check the exception for all the objects.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cstring>

class user
{
private:
    string username,pass;
public:
    user()
    {
        username='0';
        pass='0';
    }
    void getdata()
    {
        cout<<"enter the username"<<endl;
        cin>>username;
        cout<<"enter password"<<endl;
        cin>>pass;
        float x=pass.length();
        if(x<6)
        {
            throw 1;
        }
        int i=0,count=0;
        while ( i<=x)
        {
            if(pass[i]>=48&&pass[i]<=57)
            {
                count=1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;

            }
        }
        if(count==0)
            throw "password does not contain a number ";
    }
};    

int main() 
{
    user a1,a2;
    try
    {
        a1.getdata();
        a2.getdata();
    }
    catch(int i)
    {
        cout<<"exception caught"<<endl<<"length of password less than 6 numbers "<<endl;
    }
    catch(char const* s){
        cout<<"exception caught"<<endl<<s<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

***Output***

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but I'm curious: `float x=pass.length();` - any particular reason you chose a `float` for something that should be `std::size_t` ? Regardless, once `a1.getdata()` throws it throws **over** the `a2.getdata()` call. I.e. it won't be called; you go straight to the catch handler, dump your message, and then exit `main`, exactly as your code is written. If you want retries you need a loop (one way or another).

Comment: The code is working as designed. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Do you want `a2.getdata()` to execute even if `a1.getdata()` throws? If so, then you need to move `a2.getdata()` outside of the `try` after the last `catch`. Also, note your `while` loop is going out of bounds of the `password`.